# Determining AWS EC2 Instance Uptime

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ec2

Is there any AWS API available to determine the up time of an ec2 instance i.e., say I have an instance VM1 which was booted at 10.00 am and then shutdown at say 3.00 pm and again booted at 5.00 pm and so on.

I'm in need of such up time information for an application I'm building.

Regards

Comment: This answer might be helpful: http://serverfault.com/a/809326